# reversing Exp function. Logarithmic scale

Tags: javascript, math, logarithm

I am using a function to give me logarithmic scale that I am using in a slider widget. The function came from [this blog](http://van-uffelen.com/blog/?p=291). I need help reversing this function:

```
var v = (Math.exp(2.77258872 * x) - 1) / 15;
v *= MAX_WIDTH;
```

A commenter from that blog has posted this g(f(x)) function, but it does not seem to produce the right result:

```
var unscaledValue = 2.77258872 * (Math.log(v * 15 /MAX_WIDTH + 1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
v = (Math.exp(2.77258872 * x) - 1) / 15 * MAX_WIDTH
v * 15 / MAX_WIDTH = Math.exp(2.77258872 * x) - 1
v * 15 / MAX_WIDTH + 1 = Math.exp(2.77258872 * x)
Math.log(v * 15 / MAX_WIDTH + 1) = 2.77258872 * x
x = Math.log(v * 15 / MAX_WIDTH + 1) / 2.77258872
```

Comment: 9th grade math just flooded back in. Thank you for supplying the proof. Yours is the correct answer. ErstwhileIII has a parenthesis problem in the last statement, but the point is the same. Thank you both

Answer (score 0):

Just go back and do the algebra:

```
v = MAX_WIDTH* ((Math.exp(2.77258872 * x) - 1 ) /15)
v/MAX_WIDTH = (Math.exp(2.77258872 * x) - 1 ) /15)
15*(v/MAX_WIDTH) = Math.exp(2.77258872 * x) - 1
15*(v/MAX_WIDTH) +1 = Math.exp(2.77258872 *x)

log(15*(v/MAX_WIDTH)+1) = 2.77258872*x
(log(15*v/MAX_WIDTH)+1)/2.77258872) = x
```

Looks like you multiplied when you should have divided.